# Generate random number for member in struct

Tags: c, random, struct

I have a `struct` called `drug`, and I want to generate random numbers for the members `minimal_quantity` and `quantity`. But every time I run the code, I get the same values in these two members, for all drugs that are generated.

My struct is defined this way:

```
struct drug {
    int code;
    char name[25];
    int minimal_quantity;
    int quantity;
};
```

And the method for generating drugs is this:

```
load_drugs_file(){
     int i;

     for(i=0;i<=50;i++){

       if ((fp=fopen("drugs.dat","a+"))==NULL){
          printf("Error: impossible to open the file. \n");
          exit(1);
       }

    struct drug m;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int r1 = rand() % 500; /* random int between 0 and 499 */
    int r2 = rand() % 1000; /* random int between 0 and 999 */

    m.code=i;
    strcpy(m.name,"A");
    m.minimal_quantity=r1;
    m.quantity=r2;

    fwrite(&m,sizeof(m),1,fp);

    fclose(fp); 
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show the output that you're getting?  Also, I highly recommend taking the `fopen` and `fclose` **out** of the loop.  There's no reason to keep opening and closing the file.

Comment: Why isn't a return type specified before the name of that function?

Comment: How do you know you are always getting the same two "random" numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `srand(time(NULL));` to `main()`.

If you call it in a very short interval the random seed is always the same and that's why you get the same value.

If you call it in your `main()` function, then each subsequent call to `rand()` will give a different value, and each time you run your program the seed will be different.